# Javascript remove and insert items after modifying an array in es6

Tags: javascript

Am stuck on how to modify my array

I have such a sample of array

```
var data = [
  {id:1, time_in: [{in:12, out:13},{in:122, out:143}]},
  {id:2, time_in: []}  //this has time_in beign empty
]
```

SO i would like to modify my array so that at the end if each item in the array has more than one time_in its created as a new row

So at the end i hope to acheive

```
var final_array = [
      [
       {id:1, in_time:12, out_time:13},
       {id:1, in_time:122, out_time:143},
       {id:2, in_time:null, out_time:null}
     ]
```

So i have tried

```
data.forEach(item=>{
  const itemindex = data.indexOf(item) //get its index  
  if(item.time_in.length >0){
    data.splice(itemindex , 1) //first remove the item
     //stuck here on how to readd the item to the array and create new rows
       on the previous index


   }else{
     //just declare the intime and out null
    data.in_time = null;
    data.out_time=null;

   }
 }
```

How do i proceed.

Comment: I notice that the ids get changed in your array. Is this desirable/ok for you?

Comment: sorry id should remain the same ive updated

Comment: Better. Now mark Titus's reply as the answer :) He beat me to it. For any type of systematic array transformation, don't try to modify the original array, but use the map/reduce functions in ES6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce`.
Here is an example:

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, time_in: [{in:12, out:13},{in:122, out:143}]},
  {id:2, time_in: []}  //this has time_in beign empty
];

var data = data.reduce((a, c) => {
   if(c.time_in.length){
      c.time_in.forEach(v => {
         a.push({id: c.id, in_time: v.in, out_time: v.out});
      });
   }else{
      a.push({id: c.id, in_time: null, out_time: null});
   }
   return a;
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the accepted answer is good, I wanted to try making this without `.reduce` for practice. The `formattedDataNested` returns arrays inside of arrays so it needs to be flattened in `formattedData`.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, time_in: [{in: 12, out: 13}, {in: 122, out: 143}]},
  { id: 2, time_in: [] },
];

const formattedDataNested = data.map(row => {
  if (row.time_in.length == 0) {
    return {
      id: row.id,
      time_in: null,
      time_out: null,
    };
  }

  return row.time_in.map(value => ({
    id: row.id,
    time_in: value.in,
    time_out: value.out,
  }));
});

const formattedData = [].concat(...formattedDataNested);

console.log(formattedData);
```